# Should "Rehabilitation Department" be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

Which is the most correct:

> The patient was admitted to the **r**ehabilitation **d**epartment.

Or

> The patient was admitted to the **R**ehabilitation **D**epartment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on context.  If you use lower-case letters, then what you really mean is that the patient has been admitted to the department within the hospital that is responsible for rehabilitation, regardless of what that department's formal name is (perhaps it's called the "Center for Rehabilitative Therapy").

If you use upper-case letters, then there must be a part of the hospital that has the formal name "Rehabilitation Department" (probably written on a big sign somewhere) and the patient is being admitted to the department that has that name.

Comment: I agree. Rehabilitation department is any old place that's for rehabilitation, Rehabilitation Department is specific.